# How to regain audience reach on Facebook Page?

Tags: facebook

I have [this Facebook community](https://www.facebook.com/Multitut.Tutoriales/) with more than 45K likes, basically I upload development and design tutorials to Youtube and post the results, videos, and updates on my Facebook page.

Time ago, I stopped updating it regularly for, approximately 6 months, before that I had consistent 100-200 likes, sometimes more. After those 6 months, I started updating it regularly again, with the same type of content, but I only got 5 - 20 likes in average.

The only times I get closer to those 100-200 likes per post, is when I pay to boost my posts.

My conclusion is that Facebook is not reaching the vast majority of my community when I don't "boost" my posts. And no matter if I boost a post today and post a regular one tomorrow, today's will have great exposure to my community and tomorrow's won't.

Is there a way to re-gain my reach without having to always boost my posts? Will it work differently if I create a new Facebook page?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You have fallen foul of Facebook's "interest" algo. The number of fans that see a post on a page is determined by the number of interactions posts on the page have been getting lately.

Your best bet is to post daily, share the heck out of those posts in relevant groups that would welcome that, and name drop (tag) a few key influencers. A controversial or open-ended question would do wonders in that regard as comments and shares count for more than likes do now.

You may find it is a bit of a hike back up to the numbers you saw before. Making a new page would waste the social proof of a high like count. Also once people start interacting, Facebook will likely start allowing more of those fans see the content.

Facebook are deliberately harsh with their penalties so people will pay to boost. However, regular interesting content will generally work around that - you just have to keep plugging away.

TL;DR: You are basically starting from scratch until you can get people interacting with the page again.

Answer (score 2):

Recently I've been almost pushed by a friend to start exchanging shares of videos. I didn't expect much if anything as result of that, since I knew the practice of sharing posts and since some years it wasn't giving great results. I manage a humor Facebook page with 1,8M likes, she has 2,2M of a romance related page (still both fall in the broader logic category of "entertainment" in some sense). The reach of the page jumped from 2M daily to 4M-5M for 3 weeks. Then it went down to 3M but still a great boost. I think looking for a group of admins to share posts of similar content is good for activating and growing pages, similar to the collaborations YouTubers do.